# Split line from a file into different substrings

Tags: java, split, indexof

I need help in order to split some individual lines into different substrings with the help of IndexOf.

The substrings are separated with *, for example:

> Question*Answer*AnswerA*AnswerB*CorrectAwnser

How can I split the string in order to get Answer, AnswerA, AnswerB, and CorrectAnswer?

Here is part of my code.
What could I do after `getQuestion()` with getAnserA, getAnserB and getCorrectAnswer

```
try {
  InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(questionFile);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  // Skips lines
  for (int i = 0; i< questionCount; i++) {
    reader.readLine();
  }
  question = reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

public String getQuestion() {
  return question.substring(0, question.indexOf("*"));
}
```

Comment: You can use `myString.split("\\*")` or even better use a `StringTokenizer`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to split a string to n number of strings. you need to pass the delimiters.

for example

```
  String questiongString = "Question1*Question2*Question3";
     StringTokenizer splitter = new StringTokenizer(questionString, "*");
     while (splitter.hasMoreTokens()) {
              String question = splitter.nextToken();
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need indexOf, String has a useful split method:

```
String[] parts = question.split("\\*");

String q = parts[0];
String answer = parts[1];
String answerA = parts[2];
String answerB = parts[3];
String correctAnswer = parts[4];
```

Comment: Thank you i will try the split function if the IndexOf problems continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
int indexOfFirstStar = question.indexOf('*');
int indexOfSecondStar = question.indexOf('*', indexOfFirstStar + 1);
int indexOfThirdStar = question.indexOf('*', indexOfSecondStar + 1);
...
```

Once you have all the indices, you just need to use substring. Read the [String javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: I will do more test but with your example it says OutOfBoundsException.